# Querying an excel spreadsheet to find rows that don't match

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have two Excel spreadsheet tab that I've imported from a couple web page tables.  The first column is a header.

I'd like to do a `SELECT * FROM Tab1 WHERE MyId NOT IN (SELECT MyId FROM Tab2)`

I've been looking around for awhile.  vslookup doesn't look like it will work.  I started looking at workbook queries, but I'm not seeing anything that looks familiar.  This seems like it shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 0):

`=IF(ISNA(HLOOKUP(I9,Tab2!$C$2:$E$4,1,FALSE)),"not found","exist")`

Use this formula if your Data is in a row not column, since the first column is a Header column
Hlookup will search horizontally
I9 replace it with the Myid in Tab1 tha you are looking for
Tab2!$C$2:$E$4 is the array of Data in Tab2 without the column header
1 is the first row in the array
False to have the exact match
ISNA in case not found it will result in error
If will test if error will give you not found else exist

Update
 If your Myid is a column yes you can use Vlookup

`=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(I9,Tab2!$H$2:$H$4,1,FALSE)),"not found","exist")`

Comment: I did something similar to what you did.  On tab1, which I suspect of having MyId values that aren't in Tab2, I did the following: =IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(C2,Tab2!$H$2:$H$109,1,FALSE)),"Not Found","Found").  The MyId column is the H2-H109.  It appears to work correctly.